# Extracting text from URL using PHP

Tags: php, url

I'm curious as to how I would get a certain value after a delimiter in a URL?

If I have a URL of http://www.testing.site.com/site/biz/i-want-this, how would I extract only the part that says "i-want-this", or initially after the last `/`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `basename($path)`;  It should give you what you need:

http://www.ideone.com/8hFSN

Comment: Cool, you can approve the answer then.

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = "http://www.testing.site.com/site/biz/i-want-this";
preg_match( "/[^\/]*$/", $url, $match);
echo $match[0];  // i-want-this
```

You can use `basename()` but if you are on Windows, it will break on not just slashes but also backslashes.  This is unlikely to come up as backslashes are unusual in a URL. But I suspect you could find them in a query string in a valid URL.